# Ensure at-least one of two optional arguments has been passed Python

Tags: python-3.x, optional-arguments

I have written a function `def neldermead(f,x0,c,alpha,beta,gamma,rho,eps=0,N=float('inf')):` which takes a variety of arguments, but `eps` and `N` are both optional.

However, at-least one of `eps` and `N` must be passed when the function is called.

How might I include an error message if neither is passed?

Comment: By the way, got to this from a simple Google of `python pass at least one of two arguments to function`

Comment: I obviously didn't think of the right thing to google haha. I think this answers it. Check if the arguments are all equal to their defaults?

Comment: Yeah, but better to make the default `None`. What if the user actually passes `eps` as `0` for example? If it answered your question please mark it as duplicate